# If statement is executed before my callback function finishes which makes react-router-dom unable to Redirect

Tags: reactjs, authentication, asynchronous, axios, react-router-v4

Right now I am trying to implement authentication in my hobby project. You may find the code on my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/StrawHatAaron/DuplicAgent-FrontEnd). I got the inspiration for my authentication from this [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ol6z72kjy9).

I have been trying for a few days to get this authentication working in my app with callbacks and trying async things. And I will continue to do so. However, I am ready to reach out for a little help.

`protected.route.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import auth from "./auth";
import {history} from './history'

export function ProtectedRoute({component: Component, ...rest})  {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props => {
        if (auth.checkAuthentication()) {
          console.log("hmmmmmmmmm true")
          return <Component {...props} />;
        } else {
          console.log("hmmmmmmmmm false")
          return (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: "/SignIn",
                state: {
                  from: props.location
                }
              }}
            />
          );
        }
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

`auth.js`

```
...some code...

    async checkAuthentication(){
        const token = window.localStorage.getItem(AuthTokenKey)

        console.log("checking auth")
        console.log(token)

        await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/me/', {
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
                'Authorization': 'Token ' + token
            },
        })
        .then((response) => {
            if(response.status===200){
                console.log('auth check passed')
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
            return false
        })
    }

...some code...
```

I am expecting the `if` statement in `protected.route.js` to wait until the axios GET request finishes. However, it just keeps returning true and never redirects.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (auth.checkAuthentication()) {
```

Since checkAuthentication is an async function, it returns a promise object. Objects are "truthy", and so this condition passes.

To get the result of a promise you need to use its .then method, or use async/await, but there's another bigger problem: You can't do asynchronous things in a react render method (or in a route render prop). You will need to have some component state, some code that decides what to render based on that state, and some code which checks the authentication and updates the state.

For example:

```
export function ProtectedRoute({component: Component, ...rest})  {
  const [authentication, setAuthentication] = useState('pending');

  useEffect(() => {
    auth.checkAuthentication().then(result => setAuthentication(result));
  }, []);

  if (authentication === 'pending') {
    return null; // or some placeholder
  } else if (authentication === false) {
    return <Redirect /* props omitted for brevity */ /> 
  } else {
    return <Route {...rest} render={props => <Component {...props} />} />
  }
};
```

You will also need to fix your checkAuthentication function, because at the moment it doesn't have a return statement, and thus will resolve to undefined. Matt Oestreich's recommendation (from a now-deleted answer) will do the trick:

```
async checkAuthentication(){
  const token = window.localStorage.getItem(AuthTokenKey);

  console.log("checking auth");
  console.log(token);

  try {
    let response = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/me/', {
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
        'Authorization': 'Token ' + token
      },
    });

    if (response.status === 200) {
      console.log('auth check passed');
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your clear exclamation! This would have taken me a long time to learn that about react and promises. I will be taking a break from this project to do some reading and small programs to better understand these concepts.